# interchange rows and columns in java using database connectivity

Tags: java, mysql, database-connectivity

My MySQL table looks like this:

```
UIN  Body_Type   Brand     Model   Variant
1     Sedan      Skoda     Rapid    MPI
2    Hatchback   Ford      Fiesta   TDC
3      SUV       Renault   Duster   RXE
```

But in java, I want it to be shown like:

```
Fields         Car1         Car2          Car3
UIN            1            2             3
Body_Type      Sedan        Hatchback     SUV
Brand          Skoda        Ford          Renault
Model          Rapid        Fiesta        Duster
Variant        MPI          TDC           RXE
```

I tried this code:

```
String a=tcar1.getText();
String b=tcar2.getText();
String c=tcar3.getText();
//to get UIN of cars

javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel m =(javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel) tab.getModel();
m.setRowCount(0);
        try{
                Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
                java.sql.Connection l=java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Cars", "root","root");
                java.sql.Statement s=l.createStatement();
                String update="select * from cars where UIN="+a+" or UIN="+b+" or UIN="+c+";";
                java.sql.ResultSet count=s.executeQuery(update);
                java.sql.ResultSet count1=FlipTableConverters.fromResultSet(count);
                while(count1.next()){
                    String s1 = count.getString(1);
                    String s2 = count.getString(2);
                    String s3 = count.getString(3);
                    String s4 = count.getString(4);
                    m.addRow(new String[]{s1,s2,s3,s4});
            }
          }catch(Exception u){
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error "+u);
          }
```

The code is showing and error in 'FlipTableConverters'.
I am a student learning Java and this code is a part of my project. Please help.

Comment: It is not recognizing 'FlipTableConverters' and showing an error.

Comment: Please update the question with the exact error and stack trace.